# ImportError: No module named flask.ext.httpauth

Tags: python, rest, flask, basic-authentication

I am trying to inistiate a Python server which uses the Flask framework. I'm having a hard time setting up the flask extention HTTPBasicAuth. I'm not sure how I can get this extension setup properly. Please help!

CMD output:

> C:\Dev Workspaces\RestTutorial\REST-tutorial-master>python
>   rest-server.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "rest-server.py", line 3, in 
>       from flask.ext.httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\exthook.py", line 87, in
>   load_module
>
> ```
> raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname) ImportError: No module named flask.ext.httpauth
> ```

Thanks!

Answer (score 32):

Probably too late to answer. But putting it here for others.

Only installing Flask will not install httpauth you have to install it explicitly. Run the following command to install globally:

```
$ pip install flask-httpauth
```

or

```
$ flask/bin/pip install flask-httpauth
```

where flask/bin is your virtual environment running flask

Comment: Rule of thumb on StackOverflow: Its never to late to answer :)

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://flask-httpauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) you could find the reason.

In my case, the correct import for my flask version was the following one:

```
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
```

Answer (score 3):

Importing flask.ext.httpauth is deprecated, use flask_httpauth instead. 
do you have try this one.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install and set up the module properly? Go to http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/ where you will find a quick start guide for the flask framework.

Comment: I went through the install guide here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/installation/. Certainly possible I didn't get it right on the first go.